# bind template data for select option

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates

let's say i have a jquery template with this html code:

```
<div>
<span id="myfirstname"></span>
<select id="mygender" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="1">-select-</option>
  <option value="2">Male</option>
  <option value="3">Female</option>
  <option value="4">NotSpecified</option>
</select>
</div>
```

my json looks like : `{ "FirstName": "John", "Gender": "Male" };`

I can bind myfirstname using ${FirstName} but how do i bind the drop down value? I used ${Gender} but that displays just the value and NOT the drop down list with the "Male" option selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be something like:

```
<div>
    <span id="myfirstname">${FirstName}</span>
    <select id="mygender" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="1">-select-</option>
        <option value="2" {{if Gender == 'Male'}}selected="selected"{{/if}}>Male</option>
        <option value="3" {{if Gender == 'Female'}}selected="selected"{{/if}}>Female</option>
        <option value="4" {{if Gender == 'NotSpecified'}}selected="selected"{{/if}}>NotSpecified</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

If that is too verbose, then you could create a function to do the match like:

```
function match(value, choice) {
    return value === choice ? "selected='selected'" : "";   
}
```

Then do:

```
<div>
    <span id="myfirstname">${FirstName}</span>
    <select id="mygender" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="1">-select-</option>
        <option value="2" ${match(Gender, 'Male')}>Male</option>
        <option value="3" ${match(Gender, 'Female')}>Female</option>
        <option value="4" ${match(Gender, 'NotSpecified')}>NotSpecified</option>
    </select>
</div>
```